# Translate Log4j configuration from file to in-code configuration

Tags: java, logging

I want to set my logging-file name in Java dynamically which is why I am trying to reimplement my logging-file as programmatically configuration so that I can set the log file name with a variable.

I am stuck with how to tell log4j to log a certain package on `info` level.

My `log4j.properties` looked like this:

```
log4j.rootLogger = warn, FILE

log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=log.txt
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=false
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxFileSize=99999999KB
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%m - %5p %d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] (%F:%L)%n

log4j.logger.a.b.c.d=info
```

What I have so far is this:

```
FileAppender fa = new FileAppender();
        fa.setName("FileLogger");
        fa.setFile("mylog"+args+".log");
        fa.setLayout(new PatternLayout("%d %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"));
        fa.setThreshold(Level.WARN);
        fa.setAppend(false);
        fa.activateOptions();

        //add appender to any Logger (here is root)
        Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(fa);
        Logger.getLogger("a.b.c.d").setLevel(Level.INFO);
```

If I set the FileAppender to `warn` nothing is logged if I set it to `info` it is essentially everything. My last line of code seems to have no effect. Anyone an idea what is missing?

Comment: pls share log4j version, I will try to replicate it at my local

Comment: I use log4j 1.2.17

Answer (score 0):

Please remove setThreshold from appender and test. It worked for me.

From Javadocs

public void setThreshold(Priority threshold)
Set the threshold level. All log events with lower level than the threshold level are ignored by the appender.
In configuration files this option is specified by setting the value of the Threshold option to a level string, such as "DEBUG", "INFO" and so on.